# customizing Navigation Links in liferay

Tags: layout, navigation, liferay

I am installing the Pages via LayoutLocalServiceUtil (addLayout ) from hook . I want few pages to appear on menu link and few should not appear in navigation links.

and I want the menu links should not be closable.

How can I do this .. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page will not be shown if you set hidden to true on your layout.

What do you mean by menu links not be closable?